# Кавычатся ли названия фонтанов? Например, фонтан Баркачча (баркас)?

Tags: кавычки, ономастика

> Фонтан Баркачча (итал. Fontana della Barcaccia) — фонтан в стиле
>   барокко на площади Испании в Риме у Испанской лестницы.
>
> Фонтан был построен в 1627(1628) — 1629 гг. по проекту Пьетро Бернини,
>   отца Джованни Лоренцо Бернини по заказу папы Урбана VIII. Название
>   «Баркачча» (баркас) фонтан получил благодаря своей форме
>   полузатопленной лодки и установлен в память о случившемся в 1598 г.
>   наводнении, когда на затопленной площади села на мель лодка.
>
> Фонтан снабжается водой из античного акведука Аква Вирго.

**[источник](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%87%D0%B0)**

---

Гугление не помогает: полный разнобой.

Comment: Отец по заказу — это как?

Comment: Это ж Википедия: скопировала, что дадено!

Comment: Если давать в скобках перевод, то переводится название как "Лодочный фонтан" (буквально там фигурирует предлог с родительным падежом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Грамота отвечает:

> Вопрос № 210223
>   Подскажите, пожалуйста, надо ли брать в кавычки названия фонтанов, памятников? Например, фонтан Дружба народов, памятник Родина-мать, обелиск Европа? Нужно ли второе тире в предложении: Внезапно налетевший порывистый ветер — «кызыльский дождь» (-) с бешеной скоростью... Надеюсь на Ваш ответ, спасибо.
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   1. Кавычки нужны: фонтан «Дружба народов», памятник «Родина-мать», обелиск «Европа». 2. В приведенном случае второе тире корректно.
>
> Вопрос № 289840
>    Есть ли правило о написании названий фонтанов? Как: Фонтан плодородия или фонтан Плодородия?
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Отдельного правила нет, но в справочнике Д. Э. Розенталя «Прописная или строчная?» (7-е изд. М., 2005) приведены примеры написания названий фонтанов: «Фонтан невинных» (в Париже), фонтан Треви, фонтан «Самсон». Таким образом, фонтан пишется с маленькой буквы, если употребляется как родовое слово, и с большой, если является первой частью названия. Корректно: «Фонтан плодородия».

Но....

> Обратите внимание: пишутся без кавычек такие названия **иностранных** музеев и картинных галерей, как: музей Прадо, музей Орсе, галерея Уффици и др.

Ничего более авторитетного не нашлось.

Интуиция мне подсказывает, что "иностранность" здесь играет решающую роль, поэтому кавычки лучше не ставить.